# How do auxochrome groups work?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectrophotometry

Functional groups like $\ce{OH}$, $\ce{NH2}$, attached to unsaturated compounds (chromophores) are called [auxochromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxochrome). These groups tend to shift the absorption wavelength to the infrared region, which is called a *bathochromic shift*.

- Why do these groups shift the light absorption wavelength?
- Why exactly to the infrared region; that is, why is the absorption red-shifted or lowered in energy?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, the typical auxochromic groups possess (at least) one pair of non-bonded $n$-electrons and -- if taken alone -- do not absorb in the UV.  If attached, for example to a benzene ring, their pair(s) of $n$-electron interact(s) with the $\pi$-electrons, and the delocalization of the $\pi$-system is extended.

Now the catch:

1. *Bathchromic* auxochromic groups (like the mentioned $\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{-NH2}$) increase the electron density in the $\pi$-system. This is typically caused by a strong $+M$-effect. As they lower the excited $\pi^*$-level, a longer wavelength is needed for the excitation along $\pi{} \rightarrow {} \pi^*$, hence the redshift.
2. In contrast to the former, substitution equally may alter the $n \rightarrow{} \pi^*$ transition, inducing the opposite effect, moving the absorption towards higher absorption (blue) and a *hypsochromic* shift.  One example is the to compare the absorption of [indigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_dye) yielding "jeans blue" with 6,6'-dibromoindigo, main constitutent of [tyrian purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_purple). A second, that heteroatoms next to a $\ce{C=O}$ carbonyl group induce a hypsochromic shift like in the case of acetaldehyde [example here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C75070&Units=SI&Mask=400#UV-Vis-Spec) in comparison to acetic acid [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C64197&Units=SI&Mask=400#UV-Vis-Spec)

Note the use of the terms of "bathochromic shift" and "hypsochromic shift" along [solvatochromism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvatochromism).

Comment: I wasn't aware that electron density played a role.  I thought the basic premise was that any extension of the conjugation path leads to a smaller HOMO-LUMO separation and consequently a bathochromic shift (particle in a box).  Looking at the [Woodward-Fieser rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodward's_rules) even bromine and chlorine lead to a bathochromic shift since they extend the conjugation path.

Comment: @ron I altered the second part of my answer and provided some examples to support this section.  Provided unsaturated compounds often provide both $\pi \rightarrow{} \pi^*$ and $n \rightarrow{} \pi^*$ transitions, I now *speculate* the Woodward-Fieser rules empirically base on the former ($\pi \rightarrow{} \pi^*$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I think you're right about the W-F rules.